# How can I check if picked time fits between start/end time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The working day of the room X starts at 8am and ends at 9pm. Room can be reserved by user and room is connected to Google calendar. So i can pick a time(e.g. 3:15pm-3:45pm) in my GC and it should render a block RESERVED in App's room. But block RESERVED have to be rendered only if picked time fits in room's working day(8am-9pm).
QUESTION: How can I check if picked time is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this:

```
//some example data
occupied_start = moment("2018-02-19 15:15:00")
occupied_end = moment("2018-02-19 15:45:00")

picked_start = moment("2018-02-19 15:00:00")
picked_end = moment("2018-02-19 15:17:00")


//The following will cover all overlaps situations
if (picked_end > occupied_start && picked_start< occupied_end){
    console.log("Time overlap, the room is already booked")
}else{
    console.log("The room is available)
}
```